# Publishing open beta in Google Play with not released main track

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have one closed track (alpha) and a draft of a production track. And your team also wants to publish an open beta to Google Play. Is our application will be available only in beta and alpha tracks, or beta also relases production version in store in our case?

Answer (score 0):

All tracks in Play Store (Production, Beta, Alpha, Internal test tracks) work independently from each other. A change to one of them only affects that specific track. The only way to publish something to production is to either publish your existing draft, or promote a release in one of your other tracks. Both of these requires explicit actions.

You can safely publish to your beta channel. I've done this myself in the past.